# local wordpress broke after changing URL

Tags: database, mysql

So basically I am trying to figure out LAMP. I installed wordpress locally on the machine, let's say, with 192.168.0.72 ip address. The site folder is in var/www/html/wordpress/. Everything worked fine until I decided to change the local address from 192.168.0.72/wordpress to 192.168.0.72.

So I went to Options - General and changed both Home and SiteURL and of course blocked myself out of the site. I tried hardcoding it back with define ('WP_home... and the other command in WP-config and I also tried editing the respective database with phpmyadmin and I am still getting internal server error. Seems like I restored everything back to what it was but the website just won't turn up. I can provide any info, just help me out. I am going crazy here.

Comment: In apache2 logs there's this:
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'limit internal recursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'loglevel debug' to get a backtrace. Referer: http://192.168.0.72/wordpress/

Comment: Okay, I think I'm getting somewhere. In the .htaccess file the commands were like this

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

and I made them like this

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ./index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: But still the site looks simpler. It looks simpler, a lot of buttons are gone.

Comment: and I can't access wp-admin page or when I click any button I get 404 error

Comment: Did you try wiping the WP install and then reinstalling from scratch?

Comment: I can't tell: did you tell Apache about the change of URL? You'd either have to move the files from /var/www/html/wordpress to /var/www/html, or change Apache's DocumentRoot in httpd.conf (or in the virtual host or SSL configuration) to be /var/www/html/wordpress/

Comment: shanebp, no, I am tryin gto figure out what I did wrong and just retrace my steps to make it work again. Reinstalling it would be the last resort.

Rup, well, seems like the index.php page lost all connections to other pages, so I am looking into files like those you mentioned to find where I not specified the path. It's gotta be the problem, I hope.

In the website's conf.file there is a correct path specified. in sites-available apache2 subfolder I have a config file 000-default.conf and eveything seems legit there.

Comment: Rup, when I was trying to move my site into root folder, I was working along a guide I found on the internet, they told me to just move index.php and .htaccess into root but I didn't move my wp directory anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, I was right. When I inspect a page through Opera, all of the page elements are not found 404 error. So how do I connect them all back?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/LzU5guL    this is what I get when loading the page.

Comment: I tried a lot of different stuff and my current progress is that I had to specify my WP address in every possible document just to get to the homepage.
I added http:\\192.168.0.72\wordpress to each and every file possible: to the database, to wp-config.php, to functions.php.

So I get to the homepage by typing 192.168.0.72 into the browser but I don’t see the admin bar, I can’t login and I can’t access any settings page, I get 404 error. I understand that I have to restore the links beetween plugins, elements and everything else. But how do i do that?

Comment: okay, I think i got it working. 
THe site is installed in /var/www/html/wordpress and when I enter my local IP into the browser, I get to the index of/ page with the root of my /var/www/html/.

In order to get to the WP site i need to manually enter 192.168.0.72/wordpress
and also I changed virutalhost url to 192.168.0.72/wordpress instead of 192.168.0.72:80 in 000-default.conf.

How do I redirect myself from 192.168.0.72 to 192.168.0.72/wordpress in an automatic way without having to manually enter the site address?

Comment: If the admin panel is open then do permalink flush. I hope this work

Comment: Yeah, I did that and I also changed all of the URLs back to 192.168.0.72 and now it works. I don't really know what happened but it works now. Thanks.